# asp.net 4 Membership.CreateUser reference required to assembly error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

new to .net so still learning....I have managed to get ASP.NET Membership mainly working with my SQL server.

The problem i'm having is I get an error in VS2010 in my code behind file when attempting to create a user. I get a Red Exclamation mark appear on .CreateUser on the code below.

Error Message:

```
Reference required to assembly 'System.Web.Security.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e65' containing the type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'. Add one to your project.
```

Code:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Membership.CreateUser(r_user_name.Text, r_password.Text)
        Label1.Text = "User created"

        'Response.Redirect("default.aspx")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = "Error"
    End Try
```

I've tried adding the following to the web.config:

Not sure if thats correct!! but i get an error message when I open the page:

Parser Error Message: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser\, System.Web.ApplicationServices\, Version\=4.0.0.0\, Culture\=neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=31bf3856ad364e65' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`

Thanks for any help.

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't actually added the reference, though.  Right-click on the project, select Add Reference, and navigate through the .NET libraries to find that assembly.

Comment: Thanks, seems that was the problem, I had tried hand coding that in the web.config file but don't think i had it correct, so that way made sure it was.